# Issue while building toolchain with thread support using Buildroot

Tags: python, pyqt, raspberry-pi3, embedded-linux, buildroot

I'm trying to build an embedded Linux on Raspberry Pi 3 with Buildroot in order to run an application with [PyQt 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt). And to do so [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_3) and [Qt 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) libraries need toolchain with threads support.

The issue is when trying to build the toolchain with NPTL threads support, I get an error while building, saying that my GCC / binutils versions does not support the thread support.

I'm using Buildroot 2019.11 RC3 on a VM running [Ubuntu 19.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)) (Eoan Ermine) with GCC 9.2.1, binutils 2.33, and kernel 5.3.

I tried compiling the toolchain with kernel 5.3, GCC 9.x, and binutils 2.32, but nothing - the same error. I also tried with older versions: kernel 4.19, GCC 8.x, adn binutils 2.31.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not very suitable for this kind of troubleshooting. The Buildroot mailing-list is a lot more useful in this case. I suggest you post the question there, along with your defconfig and the error message you get.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep trying some more and then post it on the mailing-list as you suggested.

Comment: Very likely your problem is that you did a partial build. Please restart your build from scratch by running "make clean all". See https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#full-rebuild for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've came across your document about buildroot and I liked it.
I'm currently building the toolchain and kernel on one go, and it seems to be working so far. I'll post the result after it finished.

Comment: Building the toolchain and system in one go, worked for me. Still having some issues with PyQt5, but the system is working nonetheless.